# Sorting using linked list

Tags: c, list, sorting, linked-list

I have two fields namely ID and name. Upon inserting a node in a linked list, I would like to sort it by ID in descending order.  Assuming that it is possible that different persons can have the same ID. For Example

```
1001 CHARICE -> 1001 JUSTIN -> 1001 ANNA -> 1000 CHYNA -> 888 MIKEY -> NULL
```

The final list should look like this:

```
1001 ANNA -> 1001 CHARICE -> 1001 JUSTINE -> 1000 CHYNA -> 888 MIKEY -> NULL
```

I sort the names with the same ID in ascending order while the IDs are sorted in descending order. Here is my code:

```
NODE* insert_std(NODE *head, NODE* std){
     NODE *prev, *cur;
     if(head==NULL) return std; 
     cur = head;
     while (cur != NULL &&  std->ID < cur->ID){  
         prev = cur;
         cur = cur->next;
     }
     if(std->ID == cur->ID){
         while (cur != NULL &&  strcmp(std->name, cur->name)>=0){
             prev = cur;
             cur = cur->next;
         }
     }    
     if (head==cur){
         if(std->ID >= head->ID) {
         std->next = head;
         head = std;
         }
     } else {
         std->next = cur;
         prev->next = std;
     }
     return head;
}
```

But is is not being sorted the way I want it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: To compare strings use `strcmp` (or POSIX `strcasecmp`).

Comment: This one will be useful: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_node

Comment: Please find my solution for this problem using quick sort algo at <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11813696/sorting-a-linked-list-in-c/15457283#15457283>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your insertion function, whenever you compare two nodes, compare the two IDs first. If one is smaller than the other, this tells you which node should come first. If the IDs are the same, you need to compare the names to decide which node comes first.

This amounts to modifying `std->ID <= cur->ID` and `std->ID > head->ID`. If I were you, I would write a helper function that would take two pointers to `NODE` (call them A and B), compare them in the manner described above and return `true` if node A comes before node B. Incorporating this function into your `insert_std` is then trivial.

Answer (score 2):

Simply replace your comparisons on ID values, and take into account the name as well (for example using strcmp) when the ID values are the same. The easiest way is to write a separate function for comparing two records which does this job.

Answer (score 0):

Add `&&  std->ID == cur->ID` on the while loop

```
 while (cur != NULL &&  std->ID == cur->ID && strcmp(std->name, cur->name)>=0)
```