# How to sort this linked list in descending order?

Tags: c, sorting, linked-list

I don't know whether this a basic or not, but i only know how to sort it in ascending order.

```
 system("cls");
    if (headptr != (struct online*)NULL)
{

    currentptr = headptr;
    for(; currentptr->ptrnext != NULL; currentptr = currentptr->ptrnext)
    {
        for(newptr = currentptr->ptrnext; newptr != (struct online*)NULL; newptr = newptr->ptrnext)
        {
            if(currentptr->score > newptr->score)
            {
                int temp = currentptr->score;
                currentptr->score = newptr->score;
                newptr->score = temp;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Which part of this is responsible for making decisions about the order?  What would be the complementary operation?

Comment: duplicate of so many questions... did you try:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5526750/linked-list-sorting-in-c
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11813696/sorting-a-linked-list-in-c
or even simple google?

if you can sort it in ascending order, it's a matter of reversing your comparisons to reverse the order, like answers here mention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is very easy. Just change the operator from '>' to '<'. So it will swap the elements in the other order.

I did not test the code, but if your original snippet was working, then you have to do only this:

```
system("cls");
    if (headptr != (struct online*)NULL)
{

    currentptr = headptr;
    for(; currentptr->ptrnext != NULL; currentptr = currentptr->ptrnext)
    {
        for(newptr = currentptr->ptrnext; newptr != (struct online*)NULL; newptr = newptr->ptrnext)
        {
            if(currentptr->score < newptr->score)
            {
                int temp = currentptr->score;
                currentptr->score = newptr->score;
                newptr->score = temp;
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

Here you can watch animations visualizing the different sorting algorithms, that can help you to understand deeper the way bubble sort works:

[Sorting Algorithms - Visualized](http://www.sorting-algorithms.com/)

Comment: Thankyou! Haha i didn't know it was that easy!

Comment: No problem. Maybe you should spend some time to understand more clearly what your code is doing. Try debugging step by step and see how it works actually. Please don't forget to accept the answer that helped you to solve your problem and also vote up. Thank you!

Comment: Done! I must admit that i'm not that good in coding and i'm still in the learning process. Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
if(currentptr->score > newptr->score)
```

to it's complementary operation

```
if(currentptr->score <= newptr->score)
```

This will reverse the order.